# Properties returning arrays and nested dictionaries - CA1819

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

I have four properties which need to return arrays, dictionaries and lists which as CA1819 states, shouldn't be done. It also states that returning copies of the arrays has a big performance impact understandably. So to try to work around the issue I'm casting the returned values to IReadOnlyList etc, but I'm not sure how this affects performance.

Here are the first three properties:

```
Public Property ScheduledDates As List(Of Date)
    Get
        Return CType(ws_ScheduledDates, IReadOnlyList(Of Date))
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Date))
        ws_ScheduledDates = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExcludedDates As List(Of Date)
    Get
        Return CType(ws_ExcludedDates, IReadOnlyList(Of Date))
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Date))
        ws_ExcludedDates = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property RecurringDaysOfMonth As Boolean() 
    Get
        Return CType(ws_RecurringDaysOfMonth, IReadOnlyList(Of Boolean))
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean())
        ws_RecurringDaysOfMonth = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Is this an acceptable way to solve the problem outlined in CA1819? and what performance impact will it have?

My fourth property needs to return nested dictionaries:

```
Public Property RecurringWeekDays As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Boolean))
    Get
        Return CType(ws_RecurringWeekDays, IReadOnlyDictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)))
        ws_RecurringWeekDays = value
    End Set
End Property

'Example
'New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)) From {
'{"Monday", New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean) From
'       {
'           {"First", False},
'           {"Second", False},
'           {"Third", False},
'           {"Fourth", False},
'           {"Last", False}
'       }
'   },
'   {"Tuesday", New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean) From
'       {
' And so on...
```

In this case the nested Dictionaries are not cast to IReadOnlyDictionary. So does that mean they are still mutable? or not due to their parent being immutable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the first part:**

Yes, that's a valid way to resolve the CA1819 violation. The [documentation for CA1819](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx) mentions "change the property to return a collection" as a valid fix.

As for the performance impact of a collection versus an array, I think you'll find that for most applications, the difference is negligible. It would take actual testing with realistic data samples to give you a proper measure of that, but odds are you won't see much impact.

If however the performance difference proves significant for your particular application, then changing the property to a method may be a good idea, for the [reasons listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx). (Look for the "*Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations*" section.)

**To answer the second part:**

I'm not really sure just from looking at the code, but it should be fairly easy to verify this on your own if you have any doubts.

Okay, so this second part was more of a "suggestion" than an "answer"... maybe someone else will know right off...

Comment: Thank you. Do I also need to cast value to IReadOnlyList in the setter? Otherwise wouldn't the array in this class instance be pointing to memory which may get changed or disposed outside of the class?